# How to display data from different levels inside a nested array in antd table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want to display data in different levels of the hierarchy in an array in an antd table in react. For example,

```
{
  employees: [
    {
      id:"II",
      firstName: "first name 1",
      lastName: "last name 1",
      education: [
        {
          year: "2010",
          level: "Bachelors .."
        },
        {
          year: "2013",
          level: "Masters"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      id:"22",
      firstName: "first name 2",
      lastName: "last name 2",
      education: [
        {
          year: "2010",
          level: "Bachelors .."
        },
        {
          year: "2013",
          level: "Masters"
        },
        {
          year: "2020",
          level: "PHD"
        }
      ]
    } ,
    {
      id:"II",
      firstName: "first name 3",
      lastName: "last name 3",
      education: [
        {
          year: "2010",
          level: "Bachelors .."
        },
        {
          year: "2013",
          level: "Masters"
        },
        {
          year: "2020",
          level: "PHD"
        }
      ]
    } 
  ]
}
```

in a json like above, if I want to display each education level as a row in the antd table along with other information as follows,

[image]

how will I be able to achieve it in antd. Any guidance to solve this will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

to make it like that, you have to change the json by looping, maybe it can be seen from this example

```
const dataSource = [
{
  id: "II",
  firstName: "first name 1",
  lastName: "last name 1",
  education: [
    {
      year: "2010",
      level: "Bachelors .."
    },
    {
      year: "2013",
      level: "Masters"
    }
  ]
},
{
  id: "22",
  firstName: "first name 2",
  lastName: "last name 2",
  education: [
    {
      year: "2010",
      level: "Bachelors .."
    },
    {
      year: "2013",
      level: "Masters"
    },
    {
      year: "2020",
      level: "PHD"
    }
  ]
},
{
  id: "II",
  firstName: "first name 3",
  lastName: "last name 3",
  education: [
    {
      year: "2010",
      level: "Bachelors .."
    },
    {
      year: "2013",
      level: "Masters"
    },
    {
      year: "2020",
      level: "PHD"
    }
  ]
}
];

const columns = [
{
  title: "First Name",
  dataIndex: "firstName",
  key: "firstName"
},
{
  title: "Last Name",
  dataIndex: "lastName",
  key: "lastName"
},
{
  title: "Level",
  dataIndex: "level",
  key: "level"
},
{
  title: "Years",
  dataIndex: "year",
  key: "year"
}
];
const data = dataSource.map((item) => {
const data = item.education.map((item2, index) => {
  return {
    firstName: item.firstName,
    lastName: item.lastName,
    year: item2.year,
    level: item2.level
  };
});
return data;
});
const dataMerge = [].concat.apply([], data);

return <Table dataSource={dataMerge} columns={columns} />;
```

You can see an example here
https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-sea-urpq91?file=/src/App.js

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

An example is already there in antd documentation
https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-tree-data

Code sandbox example
https://codesandbox.io/s/9b6dxf

Key education need to be modified to children and all data related to education year can be inside the child level,

Comment: Hi sojin, the above code example is related to an expandable row, if I am not wrong.

Comment: Then the answer is very simple. just loop your JSON and create a new array with all nested items in a single level in the same order and then render the same using antd normal table

Comment: It would be nice to have something like key: 'educational.year' as bootstrap-vue . At the moment I didn't found the feature in antd-vue tables. I think the react version have something like ['educational', 'year']. https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/20837